# Creating a SubstructureGenerateModes object in ABAQUS?

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm writing a python script for an ABAQUS model and I need to create a substructure generation step. ABAQUS has a [`SubstructureGenerateStep` object](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/computing/software/abaqus_docs/docs/v6.12/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch49pyo30.html) for that. My problem is that one of the arguments of the constructor for this object is `modeRange` which takes a `SubstructureGenerateModesArray` object. The problem is that the `SubstructureGenerateModes` does not seem to have a constructor, and the documentation doesn't anywhere describe how to create this object. Below is the entire documentation page of the `SubstructureGenerateModes` object.

> ### 50.25 SubstructureGenerateModes object
>
> A SubstructureGenerateModes object is used to define the modes to be
>   used in a modal dynamic analysis. Access
>
> ```
> import step
> mdb.models[name].steps[name].modeRange[i]
> ```
>
> #### 50.25.1  Members
>
> The SubstructureGenerateModes object has the following members:
>
> *start*
>
> - An Int specifying the mode number of the lowest mode of a range.
>
> *end*
>
> - An Int specifying the mode number of the highest mode of a range.
>
> *increment*
>
> - An Int specifying the increment used to define the intermediate mode numbers beginning from the lowest mode to the highest mode.

Does anyone know how to create such an object?

I have already tried intuitive options such as

```
mdb.models[name].SubstructureGenerateModes(start=1, end=60, increment=1)
```

but that threw an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation confused me too. So I ignored the documentation and created the substructure with a mode range in Abaqus/CAE and then read the .rec file. It gave me something like this:

```
mdb.models[name].SubstructureGenerateStep(modeRange=((1, 60, 1), ), name=
    name, previous=previousName, retainedEigenmodesMethod=MODE_RANGE, 
    substructureIdentifier=1)
```

So the SubstructureGenerateModes Object seems to be "((1, 60, 1), )" which I would describe it more as a tuple in a tuple.